# Remove trailing comma in an echo-ed PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this code which returns out SQL queries as JSON

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

echo "{";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '"' . $row['RowId'] . '"' . ":{";
  echo '"Name": "' . $row['Name'] . '",';
  echo '"Surname": "' . $row['Surname'] . '",';
  echo '"MuEmail": "' . $row['MuEmail'] . '@mahidol.ac.th"';
  echo '},';
}
echo "$bs";
echo "}";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But the last result of the echo-ed text, something like

```
{
...
"678":{
    "Name": "xxx",
    "Surname": "yyy",
    "MuEmail": "zzz@example.com"}
,}
```

Observe the trailing comma, which make JS's JSON.parse() failed.

Anyway to remove this comma?

Comment: Why don't you use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead?

Comment: use json_encode($row)

Comment: Better practice would be to fill an object or an array and then use json_encode($yourarrayorobject)

Comment: As per RuchishParikh and AlexisPeters, json_encode() is best option. Why should we reinvent the wheel. json_encode() does the job for you easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper json creation

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$row['RowId'][] = array("Name"=>$row['Name'], "Surname"=>$row['Surname'], "MuEmail"=>$row['MuEmail']);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo stripslashes(json_encode($rows));
?>
```

Try this, it will vlidate your json and also solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you! However this returns an error "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /var/www/html/project/jsonLoad.php on line 20". Can you give me further help?

Comment: can you show me the code of your jsonLoad.php file?

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta `$row['RowId']` is already a string at that point where you're trying to use it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a condition to see if it's the last row and if it is then don't output the comma.

See the updated code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

$row_count = 0;
$i = 0;
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "{";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $i++;
  echo '"' . $row['RowId'] . '"' . ":{";
  echo '"Name": "' . $row['Name'] . '",';
  echo '"Surname": "' . $row['Surname'] . '",';
  echo '"MuEmail": "' . $row['MuEmail'] . '@mahidol.ac.th"';
  if($i < $row_count){
      echo '},';
  }else{
      echo '}';
  }
}
echo "$bs";
echo "}";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Best approach is to create an array of objects like

  ```
  $json = array();  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
     // create an object  
     $obj = new stdClass();  
     // add values to the object  
     $obj->Name = $row['Name'];  
     $obj->Surname= $row['Surname'];  
     $obj->MuEmail= $row['MuEmail'] . "'@mahidol.ac.th'";      
     // append the object to the array  
     $json["Reords"][] = $obj;  
  }  
  echo json_encode($json);
  ```

---

- By your way, just replace your while loop with following code

  ```
  $currentRow = 1;   
  $count = mysqli-num_rows($result);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
     echo '"' . $row['RowId'] . '"' . ":{";  
     echo '"Name": "' . $row['Name'] . '",';  
     echo '"Surname": "' . $row['Surname'] . '",';  
     echo '"MuEmail": "' . $row['MuEmail'] . '@mahidol.ac.th"';  
     if($currentRow == $count)  
     {  
         echo '}';  
     }  
     else  
     {  
         echo '},';  
     }  
     $currentRow++;  
  }
  ```